# How to select option value with css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to select an option value. Page `10` in `1 of 10` but can't find the selector. There are 3 things I want to do.

Move it down the page slightly.

Remove the yellow box decoration

Put an inner box shadow.

Tried:

```
.pager{box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px;}
```

This selected it and the area around it, when I just want it.

```
</div>
<div class="pager">
<form class="awpcp-pagination-form" 
method="get">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>
<select name="results">

<option value="5">5</option>

<option value="10" 
selected="selected">10</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `jquery` with `removeClass` and `addClass` with name `select` and you style :

```
.select{
//your style to mark it it selecting 
}
```

If you can only use css, you can read more : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I have been updated my answer. I hope it will helpful for you !

Comment: Thanks. I looked but the selector isn't listed.